# Generic interface with generic constraint is unable to cast

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting, covariance

I have a generic interface that has an interface constraint which due to 
covariance I cannot cast as i want to. and have to rely on dynamic. Ideally I want to move away from that, but cant find a way to do this.

We can think of this problem as similar to WebApi Controllers.
I will have a string coming in together with a payload. Depending on the string name, i need to choose the appropriate 'strategy'(controller/method) to run and pass in the payload.

I also want this to work automatically, meaning : I have some 'reflected' code which looks for all classes which use IAnimalAction<>, load them up into a collection, and set up a DI container. All this works correctly.

As you can see in the code, the dynamic works perfectly, however i would like to avoid runtime exceptions and have them at build time.

```cs
 public interface IAnimalType
    { }

    public class Cat : IAnimalType
    { public string Name;} 
    public class Dog : IAnimalType
    { public int EvilFactor;} 
    public class Cow : IAnimalType
    { }

    public interface IAnimalAction<T> where T : IAnimalType
    {
        bool ActUpon(T input);
    }
    public class IgnoreAnimal: IAnimalAction<Cat>
    {
        public bool ActUpon(Cat input)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public class LoveAnimal: IAnimalAction<Dog>, IAnimalAction<Cow>
    {
        public bool ActUpon(Dog input)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool ActUpon(Cow input)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class test
    {
        public test()
        {
            var cat = new Cat();
            var ignoreAction= SomeStaticInstance.GetRelevantAction(cat. GetType().Name);// returns new IgnoreAnimal(); in this case
            var works = ((IAnimalAction<Cat>)ignoreAction).ActUpon(cat);
            var alsoWorks= ((dynamic)ignoreAction).ActUpon(cat);
            var doesnt= ((IAnimalAction<IAnimalType>)ignoreAction).ActUpon(constraint);


        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to ensure that the method 'ActUpon' will always be available on my instances.

I understand the problem with covariance and contravariance, but I think there must be some other way which doesn't rely on dynamic.

Since i load up my classes through reflection and only load the classes which implement 'interface IAnimalAction', I think its safe to leave as is, with an option looking for the method name in the interface and have the code call the resolved methodname  rather then hardcode 'ActUpon' .

Updated the example to be a bit less abstract

Comment: You probably mean instead of `var test = new test1();` =>> `var test = new logic1();` ?

Comment: Yes, sry that is correct

Comment: Is this correct: You receive a `string` that tells you what type of thing you have, and based on that string you want to select a handler for whatever the payload is. Is that payload specified by a generic type? (It might help some if the code mirrors what you're describing more closely - names like `Constraint1` are really abstract and makes it harder to visualize.) If the handler is selected based on the string, not the type, that might make this a little bit simpler.

Comment: Why is adding the according `ITester<IGenericContraint>` no option?
Alternativly, why is adding a non-generic `ITester` interface no option?

Comment: I think we can see this as a 'generic strategy pattern'. Each constraint is a 'contract' towards some logic. So what i mean is, i have a method somewhere as  void execute(iConstraint contract){var name= contract.GetType().Name; var logic=   publicMaper.Get(name);   (logic).TesterMethod((dynamic) constraint); } .   Logic is a dynamic, but it is logic1, can also be logic2, depends on the name variable.

Comment: @X39 because in the logic TesterMethod i need to have the appropriate constraint class, the constraint classes can have properties which are used in the logic. So cannot have non generic ITester

Comment: that is not explaining however why you cannot add a `ITester<IGenericContraint>` and determine in there by using simple `if (input is Constraint1 constraint1) { ... } else { throw ... }`

Comment: Because then its can lead to user error. Lets say i add another ITester<ConstraintN>  to logic1 or logic2. I would have to implement this method as it wont let me compile. Meanwhile with ITester<IGenericConstraint> i can forget to implement my feature and fall into the throw.

Comment: You would already allow that user error by using `var doesnt= ((ITester<IGenericContraint>)test).TesterMethod(constraint);`

Comment: Semi correct. But this wouldn't be the case because due to above comment. The  ((ITester<IGenericContraint>) would always be valid since i send back a class that has the implemented feature. As above comment. Will uodate the source so its less confusing. Sry about that